# Generated CONSUMER_NAME on each start

Tags: spring-jms, oracle-aq

I have spring-jms integrated with multi-consumer Oracle Advanced Queue and each time that the application is started, adds a new consumer with name `TSUB_1_[RANDOM]` like `TSUB_1_9FA550C4DC828DA9E05347F`.

**Is there any way to specify the subscriber/consumer name to use by the integration?**

I tried without luck implementing `SubscriptionNameProvider` on the receiver, setting true `setSubscriptionDurable` and `setSubscriptionShared`, specifing `setSubscriptionName` on the `MessageListenerContainer`, specifying `bindAgent` at creation time on `AQjmsSession` and some others.

This is my configuration:

```
@EnableJms
@Configuration
public class JMSConfiguration {
    public static final String QUEUE_NAME = "MY_Q";
    public static final String QUEUE_USER = "QUEUE_USER_SCHEMA";
    public static final String QUEUE_CONSUMER_NAME = "JAVA_SPRING_CONSUMER";

    @Autowired
    private SpringReceiver springReceiver;

    @Bean
    public QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        return AQjmsFactory.getQueueConnectionFactory(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory conFactory, DataSource dataSource) {
        AQCustomPayloadMessageListenerContainer dmlc = new AQCustomPayloadMessageListenerContainer();
        dmlc.setConnectionFactory(conFactory);

        dmlc.setDestinationName(QUEUE_NAME);
        dmlc.setSessionTransacted(true);
        dmlc.setPubSubDomain(true);

        DataSourceTransactionManager manager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
        manager.setDataSource(dataSource);
        dmlc.setTransactionManager(manager);

        dmlc.setMessageListener(springReceiver);
        return dmlc;
    }
}
```

The listener implementation is:

```
public class AQCustomPayloadMessageListenerContainer extends DefaultMessageListenerContainer {

    @Override
    protected MessageConsumer createConsumer(Session s, Destination destination) throws JMSException {
        AQjmsSession session = (AQjmsSession) s;
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination, getMessageSelector(), T_NOTIFICAELEMENTO.getORADataFactory(), null, isPubSubNoLocal());
        return consumer;

    }
}
```

And my receiver is:

```
@Component
public class SpringReceiver implements SessionAwareMessageListener<Message> {

    public void onMessage(Message message, Session session) throws JMSException {
        AQjmsAdtMessage msg = (AQjmsAdtMessage) message;

        try {
            CUSTOM_TYPE obj = (CUSTOM_TYPE) msg.getAdtPayload();
            System.out.println("Data:"+ obj.getData());
            message.acknowledge();
            session.commit();
        } catch (JMSException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are Oracle AQ recommendations for this part? Doesn't look like Spring issue at all...

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before applying them.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I used to dequeue with PL-SQL specifying a consumer_name. I don't know if I can specify a consumer_name on spring-jms. Like some Dequeue options or something like that.